# Se queda cargando mi sitio web infinitamente despues de enviar datos con ajax, empleando un ciclo foreach y pasando como datos un Json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Este es mi codigo correspondiente al problema, en el intento enviar los elementos correspondientes a un JSON usando un foreach:

```js
    jsonArray.forEach(function (elemento) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/create_steps',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {labprochat_intent_id: elemento.intencionId, labprochat_action_id: elemento.actionId, chatbot_story_id: elemento.idStory, labprochat_message_id: idMensaje},
                            success: function(response){
    
                            },
                            error: function(response){
    
                            }
                        });
                      });
```

Aqui le agrego los elementos al JSON:

```js
    // guarda los STEPS temporalmente en el JSON
                    var objeto = {
                      intencionId: intencionId,
                      actionId: actionId,
                      idMensaje: closestElementId,
                      idStory: null,
                    };
    
                    // se agregan elementos al JSON
                    jsonArray.push(objeto);
```

Declaracion del JSON: `var jsonArray = [];`

Y este es mi archivo controlador de Ruby donde se reciben los datos de la solicitud Ajax:

```rb
    def create_steps
    
        # estas son mis variables recibidas desde la solicitud Ajax
    
        labprochat_intent_id = params[:labprochat_intent_id]
        labprochat_action_id = params[:labprochat_action_id]
        chatbot_story_id = params[:chatbot_story_id]
        labprochat_message_id = params[:labprochat_message_id]
    
        # crea y guarda los valores en la tabla chatbot_stories_steps
        ChatbotStoriesStep.create(chatbot_story_id: chatbot_story_id, labprochat_intent_id: labprochat_intent_id, labprochat_action_id: labprochat_action_id,  labprochat_message_id: labprochat_message_id)
    
        # Responder a la solicitud AJAX
        render json: { success: true }
      end
```

La funcion anterior crea y guarda los registros nuevos en mi tabla en la base de datos.

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con que se queda infinitamente cargando ¿de recibir la respuesta desde el servidor? ¿después de recibirla? mi duda es si tu problema está en el backend o en el frontend, no especificas eso. De todas formas, creo que tu implementación es errónea generando múltiples POST requests dependiendo de cuántos elementos tengas en tu `jsonArray`, con eso solo estás saturando tu servidor con peticiones. Deberías mandar toda información en un único request y luego iterarla en el backend para crear los steps.

Comment: @AlterLagos Así mismo lo hice. Ya solucioné mi problema. Ahora fue que pude ver tu respuesta. Lo que hice fue quitar el for each y enviar los datos en el JSON en una sola solicitud...